# How to access properties of one-to-Many relationships in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, one-to-many

I am very new to Python & Django. I am building a personal diary with pretty simple properties such as Months and Entries.

###### models.py

```
class Month(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    month_name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Month", max_length=20, unique=True)
    year_number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name="Year")
    featured_img = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Featured", upload_to='diary/featured_img', default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Month"
        ordering = ['-year_number', 'month_name']

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, %s' % (self.month_name, self.year_number)


class Entry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField()
    month = models.ForeignKey('Month', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)
    img = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Image", upload_to='diary/entry_img', default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date", default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Entries"
        ordering = ['-date_created']
```

I am trying to build a simple webpage which displays the Months in list form and when I click on the month I get the entries in detail view. I completed the first step but I cannot figure out how to access the one-to-many relationships between Month and Entry model in Django templates.
What I want to do is to display a page with all the Month model objects and when a user clicks on a specific month say "December", Django returns all the entries which have the month object defined as December.

This worked fine in the admin site where I inserted TabularInLine method and I could see all the entries for a specific month but I can't figure out how to do this in templates and views.

###### admin.py

```
class EntryInLine(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Entry


class MonthAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [EntryInLine]


admin.site.register(Month, MonthAdmin)
```

###### views.py

```
class MonthListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Month
    context_object_name = 'month_list'
    template_name = 'diary/month.html'


class MonthDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = 'entries_list'
    template_name = 'diary/entries.html'


def index(request):
    month = Month.objects.all()
    entry = Entry.objects.all()

    context = {
        'month': month,
        'entry': entry,
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context=context)
```

###### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('month/', views.MonthListView.as_view(), name='month'),
    path('month/<int:pk>', views.MonthDetailView.as_view(), name='entries'),
]
```

###### month.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}<title>Months</title>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Month</h1>
{% if month_list %}
    <ul>
        {% for month in month_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="month.get_absolute_url()">{{ month.month_name }}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
    <p>There are no months to display</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

###### entries.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}<title>Entries</title>{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
{% if entries_list %}
        {% for entry in entries_list %}
            <h3>{{ entry.title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ entry.date_created }}</p>
            <p>{{ entry.content }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    <p>There are no entries in this month.</p>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I know the problem is probably in adding Entry model in the DetailView and the url mappings but I couldn't find a good resource online to explain what exactly is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MonthDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = 'entries_list'
    template_name = 'diary/entries.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = kwargs.get('pk') # this is the primary key from your URL
        context = super(MonthDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entries_list'] = Entry.objects.filter(month=pk)
        return context
```

I think this may help.

Comment: This definitely makes sense and should work but my entries.html is not able to access the Entry model. 
When running the entries.html code, the page executes successfully but django cannot run the {% if %} block and runs the {% else %} block instead. 
The page just returns "There are no entries in this month."

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Added a get_context_data function in the MonthDetailView and it's working now!

```
class MonthDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Entry
    context_object_name = 'entries_list'
    template_name = 'diary/entries.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MonthDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['entries_list'] = Entry.objects.filter(month=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```